# Add picture boxes dynamically in row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to show images in a row..For this I am trying to add picture boxes dynamically. Image location is stored in databses. my code is as

```
int iCtr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = "pictureBox"+i,
                Size = new Size(316, 320),
                Location = new Point(1, iCtr * 1100 + 1),
                Visible = true
            };
           // string fname = dt.Rows[2]["FileName"].ToString();
            picture.ImageLocation = dt.Rows[i]["FileName"].ToString();
            //@"..\Images\80knhk00003.jpg";
            pnlDisplayImage.Controls.Add(picture);
            iCtr++;
        }
```

where dt is datable.

with this I can see only last image but not all images. Even last image is very small and complete image is not shown.(i.e. I can view only one corner of actual image).

How can I give size to image so that it can be viewed completely?
And how can I display images in row?

Please help
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing here. but turning scrollbars on your panel might help. Why are you spacing them by 1100 when they are only 320 in height. Are the actual inages the size of the picture box, if not you should have one of the scaling options set e.g. stretch. Set this up at design time, have a look what you need to do to get waht you want and then write the code based on what you learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try something like this? To get the scaling, see [PictureBoxSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx).

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "pictureBox" + i,
        Size = new Size(316, 320),
        Location = new Point(i * 316, 1),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    };
    picture.ImageLocation = dt.Rows[i]["FileName"].ToString();
    pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
}

foreach (PictureBox p in pictureBoxList)
{
    pnlDisplayImage.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of Image property, set the BackGroundImage property to your picture location, and then set the BackGroundImageLayout to the value "Stretch" then you will see full image.